# Show QLPreviewController toolbar by default

Tags: iphone, ios7, qlpreviewcontroller

I am presenting a QLPreviewController modally
So after presenting it , it occupies the entire screen
Also the QLPreviewController get overlapped by the status bar
The top bar is displayed when we tap on it once
but can we show the top bar by default?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

By default, QLPreviewController shows up with a toolbar that disappears and reappears at the tap of a button (allowing the user to preview the document to its fullest extent).

If you want a bar to always be there instead, I suggest wrapping the QLPreviewController in an UINavigationController and THEN presenting that controller modally.

Note: The navigation controller does not have all of the buttons the toolbar does though. (no arrow buttons).

Example:

```
PreviewVC* preview = [[PreviewVC alloc] init];
UINavigationController* nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:preview];

[self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];
```